# Methods of testing interrupts

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, interrupts

I am maintaining and developing software in C for S12X micro controllers. The ISR for each interrupts (like I2C, Timer Interrupts etc) are very lengthy, like around 20 to 30 lines with several calculations inside the ISR for several interrupts.

From what I have read the ISR should be as short as possible. Am I correct on this? Right now I am facing several issues related, like the controller reset at random times. I am still figuring out the reason.

Now my main question is what basic procedure should I follow for testing interrupts? I want to do a controlled testing, like I send one interrupt then when it is executing I want to send another interrupt and see whether it is properly executing, and other such important factors. The code is also in an advanced stage; should I take a risk of completely modifying the interrupts?

One suggestion I specifically want is in case of not going for complete modification of ISRs, whether it is safe that I disable the interrupts as soon as I enter one ISR, and enable the interrupts while exiting for all the interrupts.

Comment: It's too broad and very much dependent on your application.

Comment: Don't rule out simulation or single-stepping from a breakpoint in an ISR (with a debugger) for testing interrupts. Yes, ISRs should be short in most (not all) cases and you should be careful about what you affect inside the ISR. You might be clobbering something from inside your interrupts if they seem to be causing crashes, which might be more challenging to debug than to write.

Comment: This question is far too broad. Hint: what does the X in S12X stand for? **A co-processor, which may or may not be used for executing interrupts!** This is the whole reason why you would use S12X and not S12. But you don't even mention this in your question. You must clarify if the co-processor is used or not, as that would give entirely different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, keeping interrupts short is a good idea.  How rigidly you need to follow this advice obviously depends on what you are trying to do, and we don't know that.  Good engineering involves knowing when it's safe to leave your guidelines.

Debugging?? At this level, whatever helps you see what's going on.  From your very terse description, turning a GPIO on when you enter an interrupt and turning it back off when you leave, using a different bit for each interrupt, will at least give you something you can see on a scope that might clue you in about your timing and interrupt occurrences.   If you have some maximum time that the interrupt should take, a scope with advanced digital triggering tools can help you to trigger on the wide pulses.

Bit toggling is a very common tool for debugging at this level.  Is it enough?  Very hard to say.  Using hardware debuggers and step commands might help too, but your timing will obviously be all whacked up.

Should you play with the interrupt code?  Well, how valuable is your current non-working code.  If its not good enough, and you need to play with things to fix it, you really don't have a choice.  This shouldn't intimidate you if you use a good version control system to restore if you need to.

Comment: Can you please provide me one suggestion, in testing I gave all possible interrupts continuously and I see that the controller resets after some 12 hours. Is it possible that the interrupts get stacked after some time and reset? Or I should stop doubting the interrupts. Sorry it may be tough to give suggestion without knowing the complete system.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above point a good way to deal with interrupts inside the ISR is that you just set a variable inside the interrupt and clear the interrupt status register flags. And in the main you just keep checking continuosly if this variable is set or not. If it is set then reset it first and do whatever you where about to do in the interrupt subroutine here inside main. Remember that this variable has to be global so that both the ISR and the main function or any other function can access it. So have differenct values for different interrupts and you can handle things in the main function rather than in the ISR. Try to print small data like just a single character for your reference and prevent doing long printf's.